# How to combine multiple child nodes with labels in a single statement?

Tags: mermaid

I would like to write this Mermaid code for a flowchart in a single statement:

```
flowchart TD
Parent --> |Label1|Child1
Parent --> |Label2|Child2
```

It throws an error when I do so like this:

```
flowchart TD
Parent --> |Label1|Child1 & |Label2|Child2
```

```
**Error: **Expecting 'SEMI', ...
```

Any way around this issue?

Comment: The [docs](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/stateDiagram.html) seem to be clear that, what you want to do, is not possible/available.

Comment: I still fail to see the issue, testing the first code block on https://mermaid.live/edit seems to work OK and, of course, the second one throws errors....    But is that not because of the language design?  And no one should change the language because of this _issue_

Comment: I clarified the question. This is for a flowchart, not a state diagram. The syntax is different for labels between them. Also, did you mean that the docs say it's not possible, or do you mean it's implied (I did not find it mentioned explicitly there)

Comment: Please link the docs (for flowchart: https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html) where it states that this should be possible, or make clear **WHY** you need this.

Comment: Thank you, Luuk.

The docs mention inserting [text on links](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html#text-on-links) and [chaining of links](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/flowchart.html#text-on-links). There is no mention of combining the two together in a single statement.

My question isn't whether it should or shouldnt be in the language or called a limitation. It's whether there is currently a mechanism/workaround to do the above. If there isn't, that's fine. It's a subjective matter: I find it cleaner (and easier to order) child-nodes with labels when written in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I'd happily delete this answer if someone proves us wrong, but I think this is currently just not supported. I could not find any way to make it work, and have checked [the Mermaid integration tests](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/tree/develop/cypress/integration/rendering) (specifically [the flowchart spec](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/blob/develop/cypress/integration/rendering/flowchart-v2.spec.js)) and could not find any sample that uses "`&`" in combination with `|label|`s.